# Materials in Mother Base: Are they useful?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

So I just created several platforms in mother base and now I see a platform with several unprocessed materials in there. What happens if I fulton those materials? Are they added to the resources?

Comment: I tried with one container and nothing showed up in the notifications. But I might have missed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the materials that you have previously Fulton'd out in missions

They still have to be processed by the base development team, if you look at the side of the containers, you will see your emblem on these containers, if you Fulton'd them out then nothing happens because you already had them in the first place, it's like fultoning a soldier you already have in your base

Comment: Important to note - you still lose GMP for fultoning your own stuff... and as a super side note: in FOB, if someone steals your stuff and you can retaliate, you can actually steal it back by finding the crates with your logo on them.